# Android- How to determine the current speed based on acceleration changes

Tags: android

I have to find current speed using Accelerometer in android. Is it possible? if yes give the examples.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

It will be too inaccurate, but yeah, it is possible. By using a result of all the 3 forces of the 3 axes you can calculate the total acceleration per frame. Then by using the difference per frame you can calculate how much the user has accelerated.

Getting the result of all the 3 forces: `sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z);`

You are better of using the GPS for determining speed.